# How is the word "self-conceited" different from "narcissistic"?

Tags: meaning, differences, connotation

According to [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/conceited), the word "Conceited" is defined as:

> A conceited person has an inflated self-image and perceives himself as incredibly entertaining and wonderful. Talk incessantly about your accomplishments on the clarinet or amazing ability to wiggle your ears, and people are going to think you’re conceited.

It pretty much sounds like "narcissistic". However, I sense that there could be a subtle difference of connotation, or nuance, of those words. Could anyone tell me how those words are used in real life?

Comment: They are very close but not exact synonyms. I think that *conceited* has a harder edge to it, and is usually employed in a pejorative sense. *Narcissistic* in my own experience is more used in a patronising way, sometimes with an expression of endearment. It is sometimes said of children, with the unspoken notion that they will grow out of it.

Comment: But "self-conceited" sounds a bit redundant.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes. I wouldn't use it. *Self-opinionated* is by all means fine, because it means something different to being merely *opinionated*. But I can't see what *self-conceited* adds to *conceited*.

Answer (score 2):

Narcissistic comes from a [morality tale about vanity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(mythology)) so I'd use it for someone too vain for their own good.

'Conceited' has more of a sense of arrogance and unjustified self-regard.

Answer (score 0):

**Conceited** has more of a sense of someone who has come to learn this state (through their view of their achievements), whereas **narcissistic** is more of a subconcious or innate condition - hence narcissistic being applied frequently to children (or others who have still an opportunity to learn). For examply, in psychology, children are described as going through a **narcissistic** phase (typically round age 2) - it would not be accurate to use **conceited** in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  “Self-conceited” is a redundant form of “conceited”.  If a person is conceited, how does describing that person as self-conceited change the meaning?

Comment: Hello, Mark Lawrence, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. Your response above is more of a comment (like the comment by Hot Licks that it seems to endorse) than an answer to the posted question. At this site, we are strict about reserving answer boxes for attempts to answer the posted question at the top of the page. When you have accumulated 50 reputation points at this site (by receiving upvotes for questions [5 rep points per upvote] and answers [10 rep points per upvote] that you post), you will be able to comment beneath any question or answer on the site.

Comment: I might add, in connection with the word _conceit_, that in Shakespeare's time the word might refer to a conception or an idea, or to imagination, as well as to self-regard, as various notes in [this edition of _Hamlet_](https://books.google.com/books?id=a5VHAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA194&dq=Hamlet+conceit&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtgq3dttbaAhXJg1QKHYSiA0IQ6AEITjAG#v=onepage&q=conceit&f=false) make clear. So at least in the distant past, _conceit_ and _self-conceit_ represented overlapping but by no means identical ideas.